# Reversing a string in C using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need to find a way to reverse a string using pointers in `C`. I'm not supposed to use array notation or string library functions either.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    //Reverse2
    char *forward = "123";
    char *back = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    reverse2(forward, back);

    return 0;
}

void reverse2(char *string, char *string2) {
    int counter = 0;
    char *string1 = string;
    while (*string1) {
        counter += 1;
        string1 += 1;
    }
    string1--;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
        *string2 = *string1;
        string2 += 1;
        string1--;
    }
    printf("%s", string2);
}
```

This is the error it gives when I run it in `ideone`:

```
Compilation error   #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 0KB

prog.c:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'reverse2' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        reverse2(forward, back);
        ^
prog.c:41:6: error: conflicting types for 'reverse2'
void reverse2(char* string, char* string2){
     ^
prog.c:8:2: note: previous implicit declaration is here
        reverse2(forward, back);
        ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: You are not setting the `'\0'`-terminating byte for `string2`.

Comment: Add `void reverse2(char* string, char* string2);` before `main` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: One option would be to write the whole `reverse2` function before `main`. But some times it is not as easy as that, for example with cycling dependencies or when you are using a function from another compile unit. The line I suggested is called a function prototype, it's basically telling the compiler "hey, there is a function called `reverse2` that takes to pointers to `char`". So even if the compiler hasn't seen the code of the function, by the time it reaches it's first call, it already knows if the arguments match the specification.

Comment: For the record, you don't need `malloc` at all to solve this problem. I'm pretty sure your professor will grade the answer higher if you do the reverse in place.

Comment: Try something [Like This](https://ideone.com/RfUcwe).

Comment: @Michi, we probably should not encourage OP to plagarize, but they will probably learn from the linked code.

Comment: Aside: please don't name variables as `string` `string1` `string2` and so on. They are no better than `i` `j` `k`. Make the code *readable* with something like `void reverse2(char* source, char* dest)` and get rid of the unnecessary local `string1`.

Answer (score 4):

Your compilation error is due to the fact that you call `reverse2` in `main`, but the C compiler doesn't know ***inside of*** `main` what `reverse2` is ***yet*** because `reverse2` is defined ***after*** `main`. (The C compiler must be able to compile a .c file in a streaming fashion, so this means that everything it needs to compile something - like a function - must have been defined beforehand)

If you invert the order of the two functions (i.e. you put `reverse2` before `main`), or add this declaration:

```
void reverse2(char*, char*);
```

before `main()` then that error won't happen.

(I haven't checked your code, so I don't know if it does what you want it to do,  but your question is about the compilation error: not whether the code actually inverts the string)

Answer (score 3):

1 - prog.c:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'reverse2' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        reverse2(forward, back);

This error is because you need to define `reverse2()` before main tries to call it, simply move your code for `reverse2()` prior to the code for `main()`.

2 - you need to null terminate your backwards string in `reverse2()`

```
for (i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
    *string2 = *string1;
    string2 += 1;
    string1--;
}
*string2 = '\0';
```

3 - it does no good trying to print out `string2` in `reverse2()` because it points to the end of the string.  Print `back` in `main()` and you will see the expected results.

```
reverse2(forward, back);
printf("%s", back);
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent these useful warnings, you should either declare or define the `reverse2` function before you call it from `main()`.

Furthermore `reverse2` does not set the null terminator in the destination string and does not print the reversed string at all, since the pointer `string2` was advanced to the end of the reversed string.

Unless the prototype is specified, you should consider allocating space for the reversed string in `reverse2` and returning the pointer:

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *reverse2(const char *src) {
    const char *p = src;
    char *dest, *q;

    while (*p) {
        p++;
    }
    dest = malloc(p - src + 1);
    if (dest != NULL) {
        q = dest;
        while (p > src) {
            *q++ = *--p;
        }
        *q = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *forward = "123";
    char *back = reverse2(forward);
    printf("%s\n", back);
    free(back);
    return 0;
}
```